# "Property [body] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am making a blog and it has some weird issue. I used OneToMany joins between comments and posts model(one post can have many comments)
on post model:

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

and on comment model:

```
public function Posts(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts');
}
```

now the problem i encountered is in *show.blade.php* which receives data from controller from show() method of controller and returns some data in view about posts.

```
public function show($id)
{
   $post = Posts::find($id);
   return view('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

and from blade template, I am showing comments related with that post acc to postid

```
<div class="card-body">
     <h5 class="card-title"><strong>test comment:</strong></h5>
     <p class="card-text">{{$post->comments->body}}</p>
</div>
```

when I display the comment in blade removing body I get this:
[image: data from comments table]

i tried `$post->comments->body` but i get error
what is wrong with this, the suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: try with {{$post->comments[0]->body}}

Comment: @MaulikShah i have no idea where do i put findOrFail, coz i m directly displaying data from model using blade template

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`comments` is a collection instance you need to loop through

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
 <p class="card-text">{{$comment->body}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Or alternatively with single comment 
`{{$post->comments[key]->body}}` Replace key with index like

`{{$post->comments[0]->body}}`

Comment: i did but it said wait 7min to mark ans as correct so please wait